# How to Get Custom Field value acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I'm new in developing acumatica I am stuck at getting the value of a custom TextEdit field that I created. I can get all of the built-in field value through this code

```
InventoryItem items = (InventoryItem)Base.Item.Cache.Current;
```

but I cannot get the one that I have created at acumatica customization
here is the field I want to get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPln4.png

I already tried

```
InventoryItem items = (InventoryItem)Base.ItemSettings.Cache.Current;

var shortdesc = items.UsrShortDescription;
```

But it's not working and does not show the value inside the textbox
thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InventoryItem items = (InventoryItem)Base.ItemSettings.Current;
var itemExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(items);
var shortdesc = itemExt.UsrShortDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vardan showed one way, for completeness of picture want to show another as well:

```
InventoryItem items = (InventoryItem)Base.ItemSettings.Current;
var itemExt = items.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

Comment: I usually prefer this way of getting extensions until a recent issue on sales order where our extension would not work using this method. Acumatica support said we should be using PXCache<>.GetExtension to correctly get the extension. They made it sound like this call should not have been made public but for as much as we use it this way we have only had this one issue in many years. Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of getting value from a non-extension field. I did not use extension DAC to add the *Gift card* field to the store setup screen.

[image]

In a method I need to get the value of that field. I should check whether the order contains Gift card item or not.

```
 public static bool GiftcardName(OrderModel orders, BZWoocommerceStore store)
 {
     // "ZGift CArd W" => "giftcard"
     string wooCommName = string.Empty;
     string wooCommNameNoSpases = string.Empty;

     bool containsGiftcardName = false;
     bool isGiftcard = false;


     foreach (OrderLineModel line in orders.LineItems)
     {
         string gNameInAcumatica = store.GiftcardIdentifier;

         string gNameInAcumaticaWithoutSpaces = gNameInAcumatica.Replace(" ", "");

         wooCommName = line.Name; //pattern
         wooCommNameNoSpases = wooCommName.Replace(" ", "");
         //wooCommNameNoSpases =  new string(wooCommName.ToCharArray()
         //    .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
         //    .ToArray());
         //woCommNameNoUperCase= wooCommNameNoSpases.ToLower();
         //isGiftcardName= woCommNameNoUperCase.Contains(gName);
         //containsGiftcardName = wooCommNameNoSpases.Contains(gName);

         containsGiftcardName = Regex.IsMatch(wooCommNameNoSpases, gNameInAcumaticaWithoutSpaces, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

         if(containsGiftcardName)
         {
             isGiftcard = true;
         }
     }

     return isGiftcard;
 }
```

So, when I call this method I give to that 2 arguments, *orders* and *store*.
The *store* argument was created in this way.

```
     public PXSelect<BZWoocommerceOrder> Order;
```

In an action method I wrote this.

```
string storeCode = this.Order.Current.StoreCode;
BZWoocommerceStore store = PXSelect<BZWoocommerceStore, Where<BZWoocommerceStore.storeCode, Equal<Required<BZWoocommerceStore.storeCode>>>>.Select(this, storeCode);
```

My *GiftcardName()* method sees the value of original field. Writing "Original" I mean that you do not use any technique like this one.

```
BZSOOrderExt rowExt = sender.GetExtension<BZSOOrderExt>(row);
```